# Using AutoLayout to just rotate a View

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

With AutoLayout, is it possible to keep a View (button, image, etc) in the same location but just rotate it 90 degrees when the device is rotated?

For example, in the following images the Views stay exactly as they were placed in the portrait orientation (same distances from the edges), but are rotated in landscape.

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

Comment: Are you allowing the interface orientation to change?  Or are you only telling the system that you support portrait orientation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You describe the views in the images you've provided as "staying in exactly the same place", but I think this is to misunderstand autolayout and the rotation behaviour. Your layout has changed significantly between the two examples. Where both views were previously aligned along their left edges, now they're aligned along their bottom edges.

Basically: when you rotate the device (lets say from standard portrait to home-left-landscape) you're changing which view is the top, not the direction the top view is pointing.

If you want to recreate the look of the rotated view you provided, you have a few options. I'd suggest looking at the [visual formatting language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html), which is a good way of adding constraints programatically... it's easier then it seems. Take a look at the iOS auto-layout talks from WWDC 2012 if you want a good introduction.  You could then add and remove the appropriate constraints when the device rotates. (it might take a bit of playing around). There's also a section in the View Controller Programming Guide on '[creating a custom landscape orientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)' that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowing the interface orientation to rotate, then you'll have to change your constraints on rotation to put the views where you want them.

If you're not allowing the interface orientation to rotate, then you'll have to subscribe to device orientation change notifications.  When the orientation changes, you can update the transforms of the views to rotate them.  If the views are square, that should suffice.  If the views are not square, you also need to modify your constraints based on the rotated frames.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am allowing the interface orientation to rotate from portrait to landscape. What constraints would I need to change?

Comment: You'll need to change all the constraints that affect the positions and sizes of the views.  Auto layout is not going to do anything to help you here.  Basically, you need to change all of the horizontal constraints to vertical constraints and vice versa.  Since you can't change most properties of an existing constraint, that really means removing all of the old constraints and creating new constraints.